# Do IF statements conflict each other if they cover the same thing?

Tags: java

If you have two `if` statements for:

```
int n = -1;

if (n < 0)
    return null;

if (n <= 1)
    return "yay";
```

Will it return null or yay? Will it run through the code top to bottom and stop at the first `if` statement, or will the last one be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first `if` statement will be evaluated first, of course. `n` which is `-1` is in fact `< 0`, so the body of code associated with that `if` statement will be executed. `null` will be returned.

What might be confusing you is that, though the second `if` statement would evaluate true, it will never be evaluated. This is because a `return` statement, when executed, leaves the function/method it is inside of.

If you wrote:

```
int x = 0;
return x;
x = 5;
```

`x` would be set to `0`. `x` would be returned. Any lines of code after the return would never execute.

Here's another example, to clarify:

```
int x = 10;
if(x < 0)
   return;
x = 0;
```

`x` would be set to  `10`. `x` which is `10` is in fact *not* `< 0`, so the `if` statement's body will be skipped. `x` would be set to `0`.

Comment: Also, if you did not have a return in the first `if`, note that both would be executed!

Answer (score 1):

it will return null, only because returning (in the first test) means the 2nd test will not be executed.

Answer (score 1):

it will return `null`, as it's the first condition that matches. After the return the rest of the function isn't executed, and a function is executed sequentially, so they will never conflict.

Another sample of 'conflicting if statements' is when you create code that cannot be reached, for example:

```
if (n < 0)
    return "a";

if (n == -1)
    return "b";
```

This code will never return "b", and the compiler will probably error or warn about it. The reason is that when `n = -1`, the first statement is always hit, so the second statement is never reached.

Answer (score 1):

It returns null, because it is the first return it encounters. It doesn't even check the second exception.

When the code is run, JVM checks condition in the first if and, when condition is met, it executes what's inside this if. If there is `return null` then it returns null. After return no code is executed in this method. The only exception is when you have return in `try` block and `finally` block after this try.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a small re-format of your code with some explicit comments. I find that the explicit braces help some people see what is going on. *Just follow the program flow*. **If the function is returned from, then no subsequent statements in the function are ever executed.** (This is a white lie, see 'finally' Exception handling, but barring that...) -- it's a very procedural (step-by-step) process.

```
int n = -1;
if (n < 0) {
    return null; // no other statement in this function will be executed 
                 // if this line is reached
}
if (n <= 1) {
    return "yay"; // no other statement in this function will be executed 
                  // if this line is reached
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It'll return null.

btw in Java "If" is invalid, you have to use "if" and round brackets for ifs

Answer (score 0):

> Will it run through the code top to bottom and stop at the first IF statement

Yes, it will. If it does turn out that n < 0, then it will immediately return null. (I don't know why you tagged this question as Java though, the code you posted is not Java code.)

Answer (score 0):

Will return null.  Once you hit the return statement  control passes back to the calling function setting the return value of the function to what you specify after the return keyword.

Answer (score 0):

It will return null. The only value for the code you posted that would ever result in 'Yay' being returned would be 0.